# mvc progress of async operation using ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await, settimeout, polling

My server has a long running POST operation

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> LongOperation()
        {
            var s = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["p"];
            IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(value => s = value);

            await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        Task.Delay(2000);
                        progress.Report(33);
                    })
                   .ContinueWith(prevTask =>
                   {
                       Task.Delay(2000);
                       progress.Report(66);
                   })
                    .ContinueWith(prevTask =>
                    {
                        Task.Delay(2000);
                        progress.Report(100);
                    });

            return View("Index", new TempModel());
        }
```

I am trying to monitor its progress by a GET method

```
public ContentResult GetProgress()
        {
            var session = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["p"];
            return Content(session.ToString());
        }
```

My jQuery has a call for the initial POST request..

```
this.Submit = function(){
  $.post("@Url.Action("LongOperation", "MyController")", function (response) {

 }
}
```

... and periodic monitoring of progress

```
 this.PollServerForProgress = function PollServerForProgress() {


                $.get("@Url.Action("GetProgress", "MyController")", function (response) {

                    console.log(response);


                        setTimeout(that.PollServerForProgress, 100);
                    }

                })
            }
```

However, The `Submit` and the `PollServerForProgress` seem to be happening sequentially.

I always get the response from PollServerForProgress as `1 -- iniial value` or `100 -- final value`
not `1, 33, 66, 100` as I expect.

Answer (score 4):

> The Submit and the PollServerForProgress seem to be happening sequentially.

Yes. Session access is protected by a read/write mechanism. If you have a request that has writeable session access, then that prevents any other requests entering that same session. This is by design.

As [usr stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54378302/263693), one option is to store the progress data *outside* the session. Alternatively, you can change this to something like a SignalR call, which is more flexible in that the server may call the client with progress updates.

Comment: Can I return immediately from my post while the `async` operation continues to take place?  If so, I could store progress in localstorage of JavaScript

Comment: @heyNow: That brings up other problems, like the fact that [ASP.NET has no idea you have operations in progress](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).

Comment: Wow ok. I got this working on winforms (thanks to your blogs!) I'm trying to keep things minimal and avoiding adding libraries to my code but I guess there's no other option

Answer (score 2):

Session writes do not persist immediately. The session is stored at the end of the request. This is good for performance.

I'm not sure there is a way to directly write to the session. I don't have much experience with that.

You can write progress info to some persistent data store such as a database (or redis or even some other cache).